# "Unable to verify your data submission" error when logging into Craft Control Panel

Tags: control-panel, error-message, login

After a recent Craft/plugin upgrade, I could not log into the Craft control panel. After submitting the login form, I received the error "Unable to verify your data submission".

I cleared my browser and cookie cache.

I tried to login using a second browser and received the same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As part of my troubleshooting, I checked the Developer Console and saw a couple errors originating from Craft's javascript files that were stored in the /cpresources directory.

As an attempted fix, I deleted the /cpresources directory which lives in the web root. This directory automatically rebuilds itself if it's not there. After the directory rebuilt itself, the error went away and I was able to log into the control panel again.